# Did older versions of MySQL allow different date formats?

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have a handful of programs in C# running in a a couple of computers that connect to a server to access databases from an old version of MySQL, version 5.6.15. I'm attempting to replace the server with a new machine that is now running a more updated MySQL on version 5.7.24, but after importing the databases I'm noticing that all my programs are crashing with the Insert or Update queries that modify date columns.

After testing I leaned that the programs are using queries with the date format "2019-02-18 00:00:00Z", which used to work in my old MySQL installation but give me an "#1292 - Incorrect date value: '2019-02-18 00:00:00Z' for column 'checkin' at row 1" kind of error when I try to operate in the new MySQL version. If I remove the Z at the end of the date string the query goes fine as one would expect, I could change all my queries in all my programs to fix thing but I think it would be better if this could be fixed by changing something in the database instead.

I don't know if it's possible that the new versions don't allow this kind of date anymore, or if it's related to some configuration issue in my.ini. I checked my old my.ini but I don't see anything related to date format there, and the new one has something about date formats in the sql-mode line but commenting that line doesn't solve the issue.

```
Here is my MySQL configuration file in case that it's necessary:
```

https://pastebin.com/ndqnZwka

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the issue, I think the new MySQL server was running in strict mode even when I commented the sql-mode line, or perhaps I made a mistake when I tested that previously, either way changing that for

```
sql-mode=""
```

in my.ini was enough to get rid of the error.